# DnsResolutionFailure when Azure Data Factory try to access File Server after update of Self-Hosted Integration Runtime

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have ADF Linked Services to File Server(on-prem) It is accessing X drive.
Linked Service is using Self-hosted integration Runtime (VM) to access File Server.
I have pipeline which copy files from Azure Blob storage to File Server.
This has been working fine for more than years.

However this connection got broke after Integration Runtime got software update last week.

```
Operation on target ForEach1 failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed; Inner 
activity name: Copy data, Error: ErrorCode= DnsResolutionFailure, 
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException, Message=x could not be 
resolved., Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'
```

What could be issue?

Comment: I have seen many posts the last few days about a SHIR update causing failures.  You might want to see if you can install the previous version and turn off updates temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my analysis below are findings:

**Root cause**:

As of version `5.22.8297.1`, to improve security, the File System Connector will no longer support connecting to local disk, for example, the C: drive, as well as \localhost.

**Action Required**:

For long term solution, ADF product team recommends, customers should serve files over a remote network share instead of from the local disk of the same machine SHIR is running on.

**Temporary workaround**:

Downgrade to a previous version of SHIR, until you've made the required change listed above (Long Term solution). Ensure to disable auto-update until the action is taken.

The latest version that supports the above scenario is `5.22.8285.1`:

https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/7/E4771905-1079-445B-8BF9-8A1A075D8A10/IntegrationRuntime_5.22.8285.1.msi.

Once the action is completed, please re-enable auto-update, or manually update to the latest version as soon as possible.

Here is a GitHub issue where ADF product team is actively engaging with users in regard to this issue. Feel free to add your comments/feedbacks if you have any: [Integration Runtime Upgrade Breaks Sink Connections](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/472)